# Slower times in multithreading using Julia 1.3.1

Tags: multithreading, julia

I started recently using the new multithreading interface in the 1.3.1 version. After I tried the fibonacci example [in this blog post](https://julialang.org/blog/2019/07/multithreading) and getting significant speedups, I started experimenting with some old algorithms of mine.

I have a function that uses the trapezoid method to calculate integrals, both below or above a curve:

```
function trapezoid( x    :: AbstractVector       ,
                    y    :: AbstractVector       ;
                    y0   :: Number         = 0.0 ,
                    inv  :: Number         = NaN )
   int = zeros(length(x)-1)
   for i = 2:length(x)
      if isnan(inv) == true
         int[i-1] = (y[i]+y[i-1]-2y0) * (x[i]-x[i-1]) / 2
      else
         int[i-1] = (2inv-(y[i]+y[i-1])-2y0) * (x[i]-x[i-1]) / 2
      end # if
   end # for
   integral = sum(int) ;
   return integral
end
```

Then I have a very inefficient algorithm that determines the midpoint index of a curve comparing the area below and above the curve:

```
function EAM_without_threads( x     :: Vector{Float64} ,
                              y     :: Vector{Float64} ,
                              y0    :: Real            ,
                              ymean :: Real            )

    approx = Vector{Float64}(undef,length(x)-1)
    for i in 1:length(x)-1
        x1 = @view(x[1:i  ])
        x2 = @view(x[i:end])
        y1 = @view(y[1:i  ])
        y2 = @view(y[i:end])
        Al = trapezoid( x1 , y1 , y0=y0     )
        Au = trapezoid( x2 , y2 , inv=ymean )

        approx[i] = abs(Al-Au)
    end
    minind = findmin(approx)[2]

    return x[minind]
end
```

And:

```
function EAM_with_threads( x     :: Vector{Float64} ,
                           y     :: Vector{Float64} ,
                           y0    :: Real            ,
                           ymean :: Real            )

    approx = Vector{Float64}(undef,length(x)-1)
    for i in 1:length(x)-1
        x1 = @view(x[1:i  ])
        x2 = @view(x[i:end])
        y1 = @view(y[1:i  ])
        y2 = @view(y[i:end])
        Al = @spawn trapezoid( x1 , y1 , y0=y0     )
        Au = @spawn trapezoid( x2 , y2 , inv=ymean )

        approx[i] = abs(fetch(Al)-fetch(Au))
    end
    minind = findmin(approx)[2]

    return x[minind]
end
```

This is what I used to try both functions:

```
using SpecialFunctions
using BenchmarkTools

x = collect(-10.0:5e-4:10.0)
y = erf.(x)
```

And then got these results:

```
julia> @btime EAM_without_threads(x,y,-1.0,1.0)
  7.515 s (315905 allocations: 11.94 GiB)

julia> @btime EAM_with_threads(x,y,-1.0,1.0)
  10.295 s (1274131 allocations: 12.00 GiB)
```

I don't understand... Using `htop` I can see that all my 8 threads are working almost at full capacity. This is my machine:

```
julia> versioninfo()
Julia Version 1.3.1
Commit 2d5741174c (2019-12-30 21:36 UTC)
Platform Info:
  OS: Linux (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
  CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4712MQ CPU @ 2.30GHz
  WORD_SIZE: 64
  LIBM: libopenlibm
  LLVM: libLLVM-6.0.1 (ORCJIT, haswell)
Environment:
  JULIA_NUM_THREADS = 8
```

I know about the overhead of dealing with several threads, and in small problems I understand if it's slower, but why in this case?

I'm also searching for multithreading "good practices", because I guess not every piece of code will benefit from parallelism.

Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
function EAM_with_threads( x     :: Vector{Float64} ,
                           y     :: Vector{Float64} ,
                           y0    :: Real            ,
                           ymean :: Real            )

    approx = Vector{Float64}(undef,length(x)-1)
    Threads.@threads for i in 1:length(x)-1
        x1 = @view(x[1:i  ])
        x2 = @view(x[i:end])
        y1 = @view(y[1:i  ])
        y2 = @view(y[i:end])
        Al = trapezoid( x1 , y1 , y0=y0     )
        Au = trapezoid( x2 , y2 , inv=ymean )    
        approx[i] = abs(Al-Au)
    end
    minind = findmin(approx)[2]

    return x[minind]
end
```

Your for loop is easily parallelize, so the lowest fruit is to do each iteration of the "for loop" in parallel. It is much easier to reduce the overall time taken by doing this in parallel then to try and parallelize the internal instance of a "for loop".

> I know about the overhead of dealing with several threads, and in
>   small problems I understand if it's slower, but why in this case?

Well, I think your first problem is that you didn't benchmark how long it takes to do

```
trapezoid( x1 , y1 , y0=y0     )
```

If you did, you will find that it takes hardly any time at all. Anything that does not take up a substantial amount of time is not worth doing in parallel. If A and B is independent and they both take up a long time then you should do A and B in parallel. Otherwise find something else to parallelize first.

Lets look at what you have

```
x = collect(-10.0:5e-4:10.0)
```

and

```
for i in 1:length(x)-1
```

So basically your for loop has around 40000 iterations

Your multithreading method takes

total_time = setup_time * 40000 + ind_work_time/2 * 40000

Where as parallelizing the for loop takes

total_time = setup_time * 1 + ind_work_time * 40000/8

For comparison, the non-multithreaded method take

total_time = ind_work_time * 40000

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, it worked like a charm, the difference is huge, and the explanation was really good. Thanks

Comment: It's worth nothing that `Threads.@threads` does *not* use the new PARTR multithreading capabilities, so whenever you use it, you need to be careful and make sure you're not spawning any other threads while `Threads.@threads` is running.

Answer (score 3):

Your code is doing some very redundant work here. It's doing a full trapezoidal integral for each step, instead of just updating `Al` and `Au` incrementally. Here I've rewritten the code so that it does zero allocations, and my version of the `EAM` is on my computer 5 orders of magnitude faster than the original, without using any threads.

In general: before you start looking into things like threading, consider whether your algorithm is efficient. You can get much bigger speedups from a fast algorithm than from threading.

```
function trapz(x, y; y0=0.0, inv=NaN)
    length(x) != length(y) && error("Input arrays cannot have different lengths")
    s = zero(eltype(x))
    if isnan(inv)
        @inbounds for i in eachindex(x, y)[1:end-1]
            s += (y[i+1] + y[i] - 2y0) * (x[i+1] - x[i])
        end
    else
        @inbounds for i in eachindex(x, y)[1:end-1]
            s += (2inv - (y[i+1] + y[i]) - 2y0) * (x[i+1] - x[i])
        end
    end
    return s / 2
end



function eam(x, y, y0, ymean)
    length(x) != length(y) && error("Input arrays cannot have different lengths")
    Au = trapz(x, y; inv=ymean)
    Al = zero(Au)
    amin = abs(Al - Au)
    ind = firstindex(x)
    @inbounds for i in eachindex(x, y)[2:end-1] # 2:length(x)-1
        Al += (y[i] + y[i-1] - 2y0) * (x[i] - x[i-1]) / 2
        Au -= (2ymean - (y[i] + y[i-1])) * (x[i] - x[i-1]) / 2
        aval = abs(Al - Au)
        if aval < amin
            (amin, ind) = (aval, i)
        end
    end
    return x[ind]
end
```

Benchmarks here (I use `@time` for your code and `@btime` for my own, since it would just be too time consuming to use `@btime` on really slow code):

```
julia> x = collect(-10.0:5e-4:10.0);

julia> y = erf.(x);

julia> @time EAM_without_threads(x, y, -1.0, 1.0)
 15.611004 seconds (421.72 k allocations: 11.942 GiB, 11.73% gc time)
0.0

julia> @btime eam($x, $y, -1.0, 1.0)
  181.991 μs (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
0.0
```

A small extra remark: you should not write `if isnan(inv) == true`, that is redundant. Just write `if isnan(inv)`.

Comment: I said in the question that the algorithm is very inefficient, In the current times I have better algorithms, the point is that I was expecting a speedup in the multithreaded example, since I want to parallelize code that I made in the past

Comment: I thought that you wanted to speed up your code. Well, I guess I wasted my time.

Comment: After a while I tried to implement your improved version of the algorithm and it's actually way better than the improvements that I had already made. Despite not answering the question, it was really useful, thanks.